# PHP Pear Auth_HTTP

Tags: php

Self-Taught PHP beginner developer. I am starting to build my first PHP website. I do not want to use frameworks. I am thinking of using PEAR Auth_HTTP to authenticate users. I need to have the ability to have them change their own password and use user roles. Does PEAR Auth_HTTP do any of this? Does anyone use it successfully?

If not does anyone know of a library or light weight framework that will do what I am asking? I do not want to be tied to a framework, just to authenticate if that is possible. I do not mind re-inventing the wheel.

I appreciate any help someone if willing to offer,

Thank you,

Comment: I think that's not what you want. What you may want is a secure login system. Just use google.

Comment: Believe it or not I did! It is confusing when you are a newbie and do not want to use a framework. It doesn't seem like there is a lot of information out there. Kinda  surprised actually.

Comment: I am overwhelmed with all the generous replies. Do not know what I would I do without all the help! Thanks guys! :-)